# Как отобразить массив и его реверс в одном массиве JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reverse

Ко мне с API приходит массив [727,1527], мне необходимо превратить его в [727,1527,1527,727], пытался по разному

```
let arr = [727,1527];
return arr  + ',' + arr .reverse() // тут результатом будет строка

let arr = [727,1527];
let arrConc = arr.reverce();
return arr.concat(arrConc); // тут результат будет более менее, но числа стоят не в нужном порядке
```

Прошу помощи, понимаю задача очень простая, но чую что скоро дело подойдет к регулярке и пойдут костыли и палки... Может кто знает вариант более читабельный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

массив передаётся по ссылке, поэтому надо в переменную складывать его копию (например через slice)

```js
let arr = [727,1527];
let arrReversed = arr.slice(0).reverse();
let result = arr.concat(arrReversed);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: точно... спасибо огромное !